# wxPython: Problems with thread

Tags: multithreading, wxpython

My program keeps expanding.

In my MainProgram method in the MainPanel class I'm using some functions from an other program. While using this the GUI hangs until that is finished and I want to solve this by using a new thread for this method.

While doing this I get an error when executing OnRun.  It says:

> `Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method MainPanel.OnIndex of <__main__.MainPanel; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxPanel *' at 0x526e238> >>`

It think this has something to do with the OnIndex setting som values to self.textOutput.  Now, how can I solve this little problem of mine?

Help is much appreciated! =)

```
import wx, thread 

ID_EXIT = 110

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.buttonRun = wx.Button(self, label="Run")
        self.buttonRun.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnRun )
        self.buttonExit = wx.Button(self, label="Exit")
        self.buttonExit.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnExit)

        self.labelChooseRoot = wx.StaticText(self, label ="Root catalog: ") 
        self.labelScratchWrk = wx.StaticText(self, label ="Scratch workspace: ")
        self.labelMergeFile = wx.StaticText(self, label ="Merge file: ")

        self.textChooseRoot = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(210, -1))
        self.textChooseRoot.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnChooseRoot)
        self.textScratchWrk = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(210, -1))
        self.textMergeFile = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(210, -1))
        self.textOutput = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY)

        self.sizerF = wx.FlexGridSizer(3, 2, 5, 5)
        self.sizerF.Add(self.labelChooseRoot)  #row 1, col 1
        self.sizerF.Add(self.textChooseRoot)   #row 1, col 2
        self.sizerF.Add(self.labelScratchWrk)  #row 2, col 1
        self.sizerF.Add(self.textScratchWrk)   #row 2, col 2
        self.sizerF.Add(self.labelMergeFile)   #row 3, col 1
        self.sizerF.Add(self.textMergeFile)    #row 3, col 2

        self.sizerB = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizerB.Add(self.buttonRun, 1, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.ALL, 5)
        self.sizerB.Add(self.buttonExit, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.ALL, 5)

        self.sizer1 = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer1.Add(self.sizerF, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)
        self.sizer1.Add(self.sizerB, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        self.sizer2 = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer2.Add(self.textOutput, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

        self.sizerFinal = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizerFinal.Add(self.sizer1, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
        self.sizerFinal.Add(self.sizer2, 1, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizerFinal)


    def OnChooseRoot(self, event):
        dlg = wx.DirDialog(self, "Choose a directory:", style=wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            root_path = dlg.GetPath()
            self.textChooseRoot.SetValue(root_path)
        dlg.Destroy()

    def OnRun(self, event):
        #Check first if input values are
        thread.start_new_thread(self.OnIndex, ())

    def OnIndex(self):
        #Do something and post to self.textOutput what you do.

    def OnExit(self, event):
        self.GetParent().Close()


class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="IndexGenerator", size=(430, 330), 
                          style=((wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.NO_FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE | 
                                  wx.STAY_ON_TOP) ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER))
        self.CreateStatusBar() 

        self.fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        self.fileMenu.Append(ID_EXIT, "E&xit", "Exit the program")
        self.menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        self.menuBar.Append(self.fileMenu, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        wx.EVT_MENU(self, ID_EXIT, self.OnExit)                    

        self.Panel = MainPanel(self)

        self.CentreOnScreen()
        self.Show()

    def OnExit(self,  event):
        self.Close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainWindow()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[EDIT:] Here is an extract of the OnRun and OnIndex methods. Is there a () to much or maybe an , ?

```
    def OnRun(self, Event=None):
        #---Check input values, continue if not wrong
        if self.CheckValid() == 0:
            #Get root directory
            root_path = self.textChooseRoot.GetValue()
            #Get scratch workspace
            scratch_workspace =self.textScratchWrk.GetValue()
            #Get merge file
            merge_fil = self.textMergeFile.GetValue()

            thread.start_new_thread(self.OnIndex, (root_path,scratch_workspace,merge_fil))

    def showmsg(self, msg):
        self.textOutput.AppendText(msg + "\n")


    def OnIndex(self,root_path,scratch_workspace,merge_fil):
            #---PUBSUB - publishes a message to the "show.statusbar"
##            msg = "Please wait...Program is running..."
##            Publisher().sendMessage(("show.statusbar"), msg)
            #---START INDEX GENERATOR CODE
            gp.overwriteoutput = 1
            gp.OutputMFlag = "DISABLED"
            gp.OutputZFlag = "DISABLED"
            fc_List = {}


            #Get log file. For now a constant. Needs to be changed.
            logfil = open("C:\\Python26\\Code\\log.txt", mode = "w")

            fold_nr = 0
            for root_fold, dirs, files in os.walk(root_path):
                root_fold_low = root_fold.lower()
                if not root_fold_low.find(".gdb") > -1:
                    fold_nr += 1
                    tot_t = time.clock()

                    wx.CallAfter(self.textOutput.AppendText, ("Mappe : " + str(fold_nr) + " : " + root_fold + "\n"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All interaction with wx object should be in the main thread.

An easy fix would be to use something like `wx.CallAfter(self.textOutput.SetValue, "output")` instead of `self.textOutput.SetValue("output")`.

wx.CallAfter sends to the main even loop what to execute as soon as it gets around to it and since the main loop is in the main thread everything works out fine.

**UPDATE:** Working merged code snippets:

```
import wx, thread, os, time

ID_EXIT = 110

class Dummy:
    pass

gp = Dummy()

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.buttonRun = wx.Button(self, label="Run")
        self.buttonRun.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnRun )
        self.buttonExit = wx.Button(self, label="Exit")
        self.buttonExit.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnExit)

        self.labelChooseRoot = wx.StaticText(self, label ="Root catalog: ") 
        self.labelScratchWrk = wx.StaticText(self, label ="Scratch workspace: ")
        self.labelMergeFile = wx.StaticText(self, label ="Merge file: ")

        self.textChooseRoot = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(210, -1))
        self.textChooseRoot.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnChooseRoot)
        self.textScratchWrk = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(210, -1))
        self.textMergeFile = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(210, -1))
        self.textOutput = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY)

        self.sizerF = wx.FlexGridSizer(3, 2, 5, 5)
        self.sizerF.Add(self.labelChooseRoot)  #row 1, col 1
        self.sizerF.Add(self.textChooseRoot)   #row 1, col 2
        self.sizerF.Add(self.labelScratchWrk)  #row 2, col 1
        self.sizerF.Add(self.textScratchWrk)   #row 2, col 2
        self.sizerF.Add(self.labelMergeFile)   #row 3, col 1
        self.sizerF.Add(self.textMergeFile)    #row 3, col 2

        self.sizerB = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizerB.Add(self.buttonRun, 1, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.ALL, 5)
        self.sizerB.Add(self.buttonExit, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.ALL, 5)

        self.sizer1 = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer1.Add(self.sizerF, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)
        self.sizer1.Add(self.sizerB, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        self.sizer2 = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer2.Add(self.textOutput, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

        self.sizerFinal = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizerFinal.Add(self.sizer1, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
        self.sizerFinal.Add(self.sizer2, 1, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizerFinal)


    def OnChooseRoot(self, event):
        dlg = wx.DirDialog(self, "Choose a directory:", style=wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            root_path = dlg.GetPath()
            self.textChooseRoot.SetValue(root_path)
        dlg.Destroy()

    def CheckValid(self):
        return 0

    def OnRun(self, Event=None):
        #---Check input values, continue if not wrong
        if self.CheckValid() == 0:
            #Get root directory
            root_path = self.textChooseRoot.GetValue()
            #Get scratch workspace
            scratch_workspace =self.textScratchWrk.GetValue()
            #Get merge file
            merge_fil = self.textMergeFile.GetValue()

            thread.start_new_thread(self.OnIndex, (root_path,scratch_workspace,merge_fil))

    def showmsg(self, msg):
        self.textOutput.AppendText(msg + "\n")

    def OnIndex(self,root_path,scratch_workspace,merge_fil):
            #---PUBSUB - publishes a message to the "show.statusbar"
##            msg = "Please wait...Program is running..."
##            Publisher().sendMessage(("show.statusbar"), msg)
            #---START INDEX GENERATOR CODE
            gp.overwriteoutput = 1
            gp.OutputMFlag = "DISABLED"
            gp.OutputZFlag = "DISABLED"
            fc_List = {}


            #Get log file. For now a constant. Needs to be changed.
            #logfil = open("C:\\Python26\\Code\\log.txt", mode = "w")

            fold_nr = 0
            for root_fold, dirs, files in os.walk(root_path):
                root_fold_low = root_fold.lower()
                if not root_fold_low.find(".gdb") > -1:
                    fold_nr += 1
                    tot_t = time.clock()

                    wx.CallAfter(self.textOutput.AppendText, ("Mappe : " + str(fold_nr) + " : " + root_fold + "\n"))

    def OnExit(self, event):
        self.GetParent().Close()


class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="IndexGenerator", size=(430, 330), 
                          style=((wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.NO_FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE | 
                                  wx.STAY_ON_TOP) ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER))
        self.CreateStatusBar() 

        self.fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        self.fileMenu.Append(ID_EXIT, "E&xit", "Exit the program")
        self.menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        self.menuBar.Append(self.fileMenu, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        wx.EVT_MENU(self, ID_EXIT, self.OnExit)                    

        self.Panel = MainPanel(self)

        self.CentreOnScreen()
        self.Show()

    def OnExit(self,  event):
        self.Close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainWindow()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks, but I  met another problem. I have this in the method as well: root_path = self.textChooseRoot.GetValue()  How do I use this with wx.CallAfter? No arguments to pass....

Comment: tried root_path = wx.CallAfter(self.textChooseRoot.GetValue(), ()) but that did not work. Either way your answer is dependent on getting root_path correct I think..

Comment: I would pass in root_path as an argument to OnIndex

Comment: Tried doing that. Still not working. Seems like there is a problem with wx.CallAfter in the OnIndex. using this: wx.CallAfter(self.textOutput.AppendText, ("Catalog :" + str(cat_nr) + "\n")) . That should work right? Seems to me that what Bryan says is right.

Comment: It should and it does work. As for the root_path take care that you must use a tuple when supplying arguments for the thread target, like this: thread.start_new_thread(self.OnIndex, (root_path,)) and you define OnIndex as: def OnIndex(self, root_path)

Comment: Hello there. Im trying my best, but it just wont work. I've added an extract of the OnRun and OnIndex methods. Is the way I use wx.CallAfter correct? Thanks for all the help so far. =)

Comment: What exactly is failing to work? I merged your two code samples and it works. I added the merge result in my answer.

Comment: @Toni: Hello again. Seems that the external program is the one causing problems. First time doing this thread thing and beginner and all I was sure it was my own fault. Thanks a ton for your help sir!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use a threadsafe method to send information back to the main thread. As the others have stated, you cannot interact with the main thread directly or weird things will happen. Here's a really good article on the various ways you can accomplish this feat:

http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks

And here's another article on the subject:

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot interact with the GUI from another thread. Your callback should work like this:

```
def OnRun(self, event):
    <get any data you need from the GUI>
    thread.start_new_thread(self.WorkerThread, (parameter1, parameter2, ...))

def WorkerThread(self, parameter1, parameter2, ...):
    # do time-consuming work here. To send data to
    # the GUI use CallAfter:
    wx.CallAfter(self.textOutput.AppendText, "whatever")
```

The key is to do all the non-time-consuming GUI interaction in the main thread *before* spawning the worker thread. Once the worker thread starts it should have all the data it needs. It can then proceed to do its work, and use `CallAfter` to communicate back to the main thread.

Comment: Hello Bryan.  So, passing what happens to the textOutput from the other program is not an option then? Either I have it the way it is causing the GUI to hang while this other program runs, but updating the textOutput. OR I can have the GUI not hang, but looses the ability to get thing to textOutput from the other program? Am I understanding it right?

Comment: @sekstiseks: No, you are not understanding it right. My example shows that your worker thread can update the GUI -- it just does this via `CallAfter` rather than calling some widget method directly.

Comment: Hello. Added an extract of the OnIndex and OnRun methods above. What am I doing wrong? Everything works fine if I remove the thread.start_new+++ and wx.CallAfter+++.

Comment: @sekstiseks: It's impossible for me to know what you did wrong. I can't see your code and I can't see your errors.