# wxPython - capturing shell output in a textctrl widget?

Tags: wxpython, subprocess, textctrl

I'm learning python and wxPython at the same time... :)  So, I have a set of python files that run fine from the command line: `./scan -d test ~/Pictures` -- for instance will create a database of my pictures called "test."

I've been working diligently on a front end for this (I didn't write the original command line python files), and I can get it to run using:

```
def bt_ScanUpdateClick(self, event):
    self.SetSizeWH(450,360)

    ## DEBUG
    self.tc_MainDatabase.Value = "test.db"


    if self.tc_MainDatabase.Value == "":
        self.LogWindow.Value += "ERROR:\tNo database name selected!\n"
    else:
        scanCMD = "./scan -d " + self.tc_MainDatabase.Value + " "

        numLines=0
        maxLines=(int(self.multiText.GetNumberOfLines()))

        if self.multiText.GetLineText(numLines) == "":
            self.LogWindow.Value += "ERROR\tNo folder selected to scan!\n"
        else:
            self.LogWindow.Value += "Running Scan...\n\n"
            while (numLines < maxLines):
                scanCMD += str(self.multiText.GetLineText(numLines)) + " "
                numLines += 1

            self.LogWindow.Value += scanCMD

            p = subprocess.Popen([scanCMD],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
            self.LogWindow.Value += p.communicate()[0]
```

This presents a problem for me:

1. Once I click the Button to activate
   this, it doesn't actually even get
   to the self.SetSizeWH(450,360) part
   of the function.  It just stays in a
   "down" state.  When
   the command is done, the app comes
   back to life with everything in the
   output window (self.LogView) already... I would
   like to get the output in a more
   'realtime' way... possible?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Between Bryan's answer above and this link: [wxpython: capturing an output from subprocess in realtime][1]... I got this working!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677248/wxpython-capturing-an-output-from-subprocess-in-real-time/6680170#6680170

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly speaking, screen updates happen during each iteration of the event loop. While your code is running, the event loop is stuck in the same iteration and thus screen updates can't happen.

To work around this you need to run your long-running task in a separate thread or process. Because wxPython is single-threaded, any updates to the GUI (such as writing the lines of output) must be done in the main thread. To do that, your worker thread can use `wx.CallAfter` which will schedule a command to be run in the GUI thread at its earliest convenience.

For more information see the page [Long Running Tasks](http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks) on the wxPython wiki, and see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290791/wxpython-problems-with-thread/6291157#6291157) to the question [wxPython: Problems with thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6290791/7432) on this website.